# What is an azure role?

Tags: azure, azure-caching

I'm reading [this](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/archive/msdn-magazine/2014/august/microsoft-azure-use-distributed-cache-in-microsoft-azure#deploying-distributed-cache-in-azure) article on distributed caching in Azure. Being new to Azure I'm trying to understand what they mean when they use the term "role" in the following context:

> In-Role Cache You can deploy an in-role cache on a co-located or
> dedicated role in Azure. Co-located means your application is also
> running on that VM and dedicated means it’s running only the cache.
> Although a good distributed cache provides elasticity and high
> availability, there’s overhead associated with adding or removing
> cache servers from the cache cluster. Your preference should be to
> have a stable cache cluster. You should add or remove cache servers
> only when you want to scale or reduce your cache capacity or when you
> have a cache server down.
>
> The in-role cache is more volatile than other deployment options
> because Azure can easily start and stop roles. In a co-located role,
> the cache is also sharing CPU and memory resources with your
> applications. For one or two instances, it’s OK to use this deployment
> option. It’s not suitable for larger deployments, though, because of
> the negative performance impact.
>
> You can also consider using a dedicated in-role cache. Bear in mind
> this cache is deployed as part of your cloud service and is only
> visible within that service. You can’t share this cache across
> multiple apps. Also, the cache runs only as long as your service is
> running. So, if you need to have the cache running even when you stop
> your application, don’t use this option.
>
> Microsoft Azure Cache and NCache for Azure both offer the in-role
> deployment option. You can make Memcached run this configuration with
> some tweaking, but you lose data if a role is recycled because
> Memcached doesn’t replicate data.

They talk about In-Role cache, cache service, cache VMs and multi-region cache VMs.

I understand cache services to be "server-less" meaning you don't manage the server or cluster, Azure
does all of that, as apposed to cache VMs where you handle deployment of the server and the cache solution on that server.

How does In-Role cache differ, and what is a "role"?  I usually think of role as the definition of how a user participates in a given system, and it establishes the capabilities or permissions that members of that role would need within the system to fulfill their duties.  This seems different than that.

Answer (score 1):

It's legacy. In the past, there were  Azure In-Role Cache and the Azure Managed Cache Service. The recommendation is to use Azure Redis Cache now:

https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/blog/azure-managed-cache-and-in-role-cache-services-to-be-retired-on-11-30-2016/

Comment: That becomes clearer now.  Do you know if the Azure Redis Cache would support near cache either in-process or out-process?  I guess that depends more on the cache client.